# How I apply review to get publish_actions permission for a Windows application written in Win API/C++?

Tags: windows, facebook, review, publish-actions

I created and used application softwares(exe file written in C++ with Win SDK) of Windows OS(Win7) which has a function to upload(post) user photos to Facebook. They were working fine but now it is not possible to post photos to Facebook and I got to know I need get my application reviewd for public_actions permission. I tried to do it but could not find way to submit since there's no category for Windows application. How can I do it? I think the reviewers need to 'run' the app and it looks OK for andriod, iOS, Win8 apps, and Web site since reviewers can access to them by codes or URL for the apps but I have no idea how to make it for my Windows application. It is big size application with lots of images over 1Gbytes. Will it be OK to use an FTP account for the reviewers to download and review it?

Answer (score 0):

In your review notes you can explicitly mention that this is a Windows application. You will need to provide as much screenshots as possible or preferably, a screencast where you show how you use the Facebook integration.

To get all the required fields, you can fill in the website for your application (if you have one) or an other website. Just make sure to mention that in your reviewer notes.

That should work with getting your app reviews.

ps: this question actually is not appropriate for Stackoverflow. I suggested using the [Facebook Developer Community](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) group for these kind of questions (non-technical).